# How to make profit when the stock price is in Out of Money?

Tags: options, put-options

I'm so confused by the [article](https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/markets/trader-pockets-windfall-after-betting-dollar49-million-against-sandp-500/ar-BBXLUsA) in Marketwatch where the author says a profit is made when the stock price is out of money.

Per that article, I assume the trader bought options for a strike price of 2980. The index price dropped from 3120 to 3080, and the trader made profit on it. How is that possible?

Comment: The article states that  the unidentified investor bought 23,000 put options with a strike price of 2980.  When the market dipped on Wednesday they sold 8,000 lots to realise a profit of $13 million.  Buying put options is profitable when the underlying asset goes down in price.  Is this what is confusing you?

Comment: My understanding is that to make a profit out of *selling PUT* is only when the price is in-the-money. In this case, for example if the price is 2700, the price is below the strike price and he can make a profit. What is confusing is the price was 3080 which is out-of-money.

Comment: The price of an option changes on a daily basis regardless of whether they are in-the-money or out-of-the-money.  In this case, the market moved in his favour so investors were willing to pay a bit more for the option because the index was moving closer to the strike price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Per that article, I assume the trader bought options for a strike price of 2980. The index price dropped from 3120 to 3080, and the trader made profit on it. How is that possible?

Per your comment:

> My understanding is that to make a profit out of selling PUT is only when the price is in-the-money.

The problem is that you understanding is incorrect.  Barring a sudden change in implied volatility, a put's price will increase in value immediately if the price of the underlying drops.

Here are today's closing quotes for the Jan 17th SPY puts.

> Str ........ Bid . Ask . Last
>
> 300   SPY 2.81    2.82    2.80
>
> 301   SPY 2.98    2.99    3.04
>
> 302   SPY 3.17    3.19    3.19
>
> 303   SPY 3.38    3.40    3.45

Let's pretend that these are a snapshot from during the day.  If you bought the $300 put for $2.82 and the SPY immediately dropped 3 points, it would be worth $3.38 (the same as the $303 quote) for a gain of $1.16

Your reference only making money if ITM  refers to whether the put has any intrinsic value at expiration.